# TF 2.6: Backbone not present in model.summary

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have subclassed the `tf.keras.Model` class and did what I consider to be transfer learning. Here's the code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.xception import Xception

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, input_shape, num_classes=5, dropout_rate=0.5):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.weight_dict = {}
    self.weight_dict['backbone'] = Xception(input_shape=input_shape, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    self.weight_dict['backbone'].trainable = False
    self.weight_dict['outputs'] = Conv2D(num_classes, (1, 1), padding="same", activation="softmax")

  def call(self, inputs, training=False):
    x = self.weight_dict['backbone'](inputs)
    x = self.weight_dict['outputs'](x)
    return x

model = MyModel(input_shape=(256, 256, 3))
model.compute_output_shape(input_shape=(None, 256, 256, 3))
model.summary()
```

Here's the output of `model.summary()`:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            multiple                  10245     
=================================================================
Total params: 20,871,725
Trainable params: 10,245
Non-trainable params: 20,861,480
```

I suppose that the backbone has successfully been initialized. However, why does it not show up in the output of `.summary()`? Can I be assured that the weights will get saved properly (if I use `model.save()`)?

Also, would you consider this a good/normal way to subclass `tf.keras` models and do transfer learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructuring this way would give you the correct `model.summary()`

```
IMG_SHAPE = (256, 256, 3)
base_model = Xception(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, weights='imagenet', 
include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE)
x = base_model(inputs, training=False)
outputs = Conv2D(num_classes, (1,1), padding="same", activation="softmax")(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
```

Also, did you mean to use a `Dense` layer as the final output? Because usually, ReLU activation is used for outputs of `Conv2D` layers.
To see the proper way to use models for transfer learning, you can have a look at examples from the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

Comment: Thank you for everything! It is working now. And yes, it should definitely not be `Conv2D` at the end!